# Adding an element in xml based on match using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

I have xml entries as follows:

```
<employee>
<component name="address">
<property name="city" value="Bangalore">
<property name="state" value="Karnataka">
<component/>
<component name="info">
<property name="name" value="Alok"></property>
<property name="age" value="25"></property>
</component>
</employee>
```

So for entry in info field, I want to add an element with position as engineer like below:

```
<property name="position" value ="engineer"></property>
```

I am trying to achieve this by doing

```
<xsl:template match="/employee/component[@name='info']">
  <xsl:if test="not(property[@name='position'])">
  <xsl:element name="property">
  <xsl:attribute name="position">position</xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:attribute name="value">engineer</xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

But what it is doing is completely removing the info block and adding line

Need suggestions on correct way of implementing this.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your template, you are creating a new element, but you are tell XSLT to also copy the existing `component` node and its child nodes. You are effectively saying when you find a matching `component` node, create a new node instead.

What you need to do, is add code to copy the existing node, like so

```
<xsl:template match="/employee/component[@name='info']">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <xsl:if test="not(property[@name='position'])">
            <xsl:element name="property">
                <xsl:attribute name="position">position</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="value">engineer</xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

This can be simplified though by moving the condition in the `xsl:if` to the template match instead. Also, there is no need to use `xsl:element` and `xsl:attribute` here, just write out the new element directly.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/employee/component[@name='info'][not(property[@name='position'])]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <property position="position" name="engineer" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note the use of the [Identity Template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) in the transformation to copy all other existing nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot Tim. It is doing what I wanted to do.